# SIR-Model in Maple

Tags: dynamical-systems, maple

This is my assignment I've been stuck on for a good part of the day.  I'm confused because example's I've looked at would do part 3 before part 1 because they use substitution of $$u=S/N$$ $$v=I/N $$ $$w=R/N$$ and then substitute part 3 into the equations before writing them in maple.  Maple says I'm recursive when I try to write the equations.  Also why are we replacing the equation N for R; when it's the birth rate in S we don't like; wouldn't we want to replace S? Ugh any input would help just frustrating not even getting equations into Maple at this point and don't want to do it wrong because if part 1 is wrong parts 2-9 will be too.

The SIR model takes a certain proportion of the infectives per time period and removes
them. This removal can come about from being cured (and hence becoming immune) or
being dead. Examples of such diseases are smallpox, measles and chicken pox. Usually we
think of SIR models as modelling epidemics, but we can also have endemic disease states
if we include a fixed birthrate B (not per capita, but rather a fixed number ). Finally,
we have a death rate d on the whole population N and this can be apportioned to each
part of the model and a disease-related death rate 0 < c on infectives. (As usual, all
parameters are non-negative.) The model is
$$(d/dt)* S(t) = B − β I(t) S(t) − d S(t)$$

$$(d/dt)* I(t) = β I(t) S(t) − γ I(t) − c I(t) − d I(t) $$

$$(d/dt)* R(t) = γ I(t) − d R(t) $$ where R(t) is the number of removeds. Note that S + I + R = N, but we cannot
non-dimensionalize here because of the birthrate. However, if we add the equations, we
obtain
$$(d/dt)* N(t) = B − c I(t) − d N(t)$$
and this can be used in place of the removed equation. Again, since the population is
open, we cannot reduce to two equations. (Use something like F (for “fectives”) instead
of I since Maple reserves I for the imaginary number i.)

(1) Write the system of equations for S, F, N in Maple.

(2) Find the fixed (or equilibrium) points for the system. Note what the disease-free
state is and what the endemic state (i.e. coexistence state) is.

(3) Show that the basic reproductive ratio is
$R_0 =(β*B)/(γ + c + d)d$

.
(Hint: Look at what you get for N in the disease-free state and use the fact that
$ 1/(γ + c + d)$
is the time spent infected.)

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.uow.edu.au/~mnelson/teaching.dir/math111.dir/code.dir/endemic.html or http://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=127836 or http://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=153879 or http://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=153877 as guides?

Comment: No I have not.  I have a project coming up where those may be useful (especially the first link) but it seems like these are more for problems involving initial infection values which I do not have.

Comment: Thanks I just haven't come up with the actual equations in respect to u,v, and w yet